# How can I store/access an SDF file as a resource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a database that is a necessity in the program I am developing, and thus forth, I would like to integrate it into the assembly. I have set the build action to resource, but have not really any idea how I would go about accessing its directory in order to connect to the database:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = Commands.sdf";
```

This gives me the error, "The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database"

So, I vainly attempted to use the DataDirectory substring like so:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|Commands.sdf";
```

Only to produce the same error. I have not the slightest idea how to properly access the directory of the resource assembly, and could not find *any* useful information on the topic online, hence the reason I joined SO!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include more details of your problem, in particular what is the structure of your solution and what are the settings you speak of. Consider also reading our [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask good questions, and how do things work here.

Comment: Will the database be restored to its original content when the application restarts? You did realize the sdf file needs to exist on disk so you need to read it and save it before it can be used?

Comment: Ah, yes, I seem to have gotten so caught up in the fact that I didn't know how to implement a database into assembly, that I forgot that it would be pointless to do so anyhow!

Comment: Excuse my error. In any case, I have come to read this site frequently and it's about time I made an account regardless :)